# Android Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED] after adb tries to uninstall

Tags: android, adb

Many times during developing, I will be on an older branch that has a higher version number of the app that I'm developing. Thus, when I run my code on my device, adb will try to uninstall the app (with the higher version) to install my working branch (which has a lower version).

After adb tries to do this, I often get the error INSTALL_FAILED_UID_CHANGED. I assume this is due to adb screwing up the uninstall somehow, and now the phone thinks there is already a version of the app installed? Either way, after this I have to reset my phone in order for my app to be installed again.

I've looked up some solutions to this problem, but all of them seem to rely on the fact that the phone is rooted and that you have root access. Is there any way to solve this problem without root access?

Comment: There are a few solutions circling around that you can try but I ran into this issue and none of them worked for me. I had to reset my phone. Thats how I learned to have a phone specifically for development.

Comment: I have had this happen before, I have always been fine manually uninstalling the app.

Comment: yeah, it always works if i uninstall it manually, but if i let adb uninstall it then this problem occurs

Comment: Does it work if you just run the same adb uninstall command after again? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076104/app-cannot-be-installed-after-bad-uninstall