# App cannot be installed after bad uninstall

Tags: android, eclipse, root

Using Eclipse, or even by using an Exported Apk, The App Refuses to install,

LogCat says :

```
12-03 21:25:34.310: W/PackageManager(1073): Package com.app.example signatures 
do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
```

But the Problem is that I have already uninstalled the App before installing it again, I have tried to reboot in Recovery > Wipe Cache/Wipe Dalvik Cache with no luck, I am running LolliPop 5.1 & I Removed the Guest Account too with no luck.

The Apk install fine on Others Devices, So there must be something wrong with My Device(using a Custom ROM),

I have also tried adb pm list packages but the App is Not Listed.

is there something to delete, if so where,

Note : It's maybe due to a Bad Uninstall Process, i have manually unistalled this App before using Root Browser then with the Package Manager as usual,

What can be wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: If you go to settings > apps, can you still see the app listed there? does it say not installed for this user?

Comment: @jmols Not Listed at All & i have removed the Guest Account with no luck, this is a Very Strange Problem, i think that the Question we should Ask is : Where does The Package Installer Look for The Apps/Signature when installing an App...

Comment: Can you try 'adb uninstall <package-name>'? I've had a similar issue before caused by a bad uninstall.

Comment: Does no work too DELETE_FAILED-INTERNAL_ERROR

Comment: My bad it's was an error, instead of typing <uninstall> i Always type <unistall>, English is Not my Native Language, The operation show : success then : DELETE_FAILED-INTERNAL_ERROR if i try again(already uninstalled), You can post it as Answer, Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very rare cases an uninstall can go wrong causing the packagemanager to indicate that the app isn't installed anymore. The command:

```
adb shell 'pm list packages -f'
```

would not return the app package, nor would you find the app under settings.

However, the app cannot be installed anymore because the OS still thinks its there somehow.

To fix this, just run:

```
adb uninstall <package-name>
```

Note that: in my experience the OS would figure out the app isn't installed anymore by itself after a day or so. (Thus autofixing the issue)